# How do I share a video from Instagram to Twitter using IFTTT

Tags: facebook, twitter, ifttt

I am wondering how to share video from Instagram to Twitter, so that it shows up as a native twitter video. There are multiple apps on IFTTT, but they only work for pictures and not videos.

Has anyone else had this same issue?

I've tried e-mailing the developers, but no luck.

Also there's not as much information available through Google, as I assume this is relatively new thing.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, IFTTT don't support Twitter videos. These are the only actions they support:
[image]

If you're interested in programming something yourself, you can look at the [Twitter API for uploading media](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/overview).

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling it wasn't possible.

Answer (score -1):

As Terence said, IFTTT integrations only support photos.

Alternatively, you can use [tweetgram.me](https://tweetgram.me) to automatically share your Instagram photos and videos as native Tweets.

[TweetGram](https://tweetgram.me) supports videos fully and is free to use.

Disclaimer: I am the developer of TweetGram.